# php merge/push array into other array

Tags: php

I just cannot get this fairly simple thing right.

I create many arrays like this:

```
foreach( $terms as $term ){
  $single_attribute = array();
  $archive_link = get_term_link( $term->slug, $attribute['name'] );
  array_push( $single_attribute, $term->name, $archive_link);
}
```

Which generates many arrays like following:

```
Array ( [0] => attribute_1  [1] => http://domain.com/products/attribute_1/ )
```

I need to push/merge (not sure about correct naming here) each of these arrays into one big array, so that the final result would be liek following:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => attribute_1  [1] => http://domain.com/products/attribute_1 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => attribute_2 [1] => http://domain.com/products/attribute_2 ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more elegant solution without using `array_push` would be:

```
    foreach( $terms as $term ){
      $archive_link = get_term_link( $term->slug, $attribute['name'] );
      $single_attribute[] = array($term->name, $archive_link) );
    }

$final_array[] = $single_attribute;
```

Which would give you your expected output.

Answer (score 2):

`$single_attribute` is getting defined in every iteration with empty array. Define the array outside the loop.

```
$single_attribute = array();

foreach( $terms as $term ){

       $archive_link = get_term_link( $term->slug, $attribute['name'] );

       array_push( $single_attribute, array($term->name, $archive_link) );                                                                                      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php), you shouldn't use `array_push()` for this task:

> Note: If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's
>   better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of
>   calling a function.

Do something like this:

```
$attributes = array();
foreach($terms as $term) {
    $archive_link = get_term_link($term->slug, $attribute['name']);
    $attributes[] = array($term->name, $archive_link);
}
```